# Integration Services double to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm using Integration Services to load data from an Excel file to SQL Server table. When I try to send a number stored as `double (DT_R8)` into a database column where data are stored as `varchar(50)` I find a queer rounding.

For example consider data in first row first column of above image. Original value is 31.35 but as a string it's stored as shown below

[image]

I already tried to use a Delivered Column transformation to cast to string before exporting to SQL, I also added a Round(x, 5) but I get the same result.
How can I solve this problem given that I can't change SQL column data type?

Comment: SSIS has strange memory so once close and start it again after that try with money data type

Comment: I solved by deriving column with data type `currency [DT_CY]`

Comment: in SSIS language Money is nothing but Currency [DT-CY] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution was changing the input type from `double (DT_R8)` to `currency [DT_CY]`. It seems that the rounding performed on `double (DT_R8)` make its use difficult when parsing is somehow involved in the export process.